# Firebase Update Data Not work using FirebaseData.net nuget

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I am using FirebaseDatabase.net plugin in my xamarin mobile app.

I am able to insert and read data,but unable to use update.I am using PutAsync method:

Example:

```
FirebaseClient firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://******.firebaseio.com/");
await firebase.Child("Users").Child("nhUHmmu8HJimlo").PutAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));
```

in the last line I am not able to use multiple 'Child' keyword for this PutAsync method,so how to solve this?Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: " I am not able to use multiple 'Child' keyword" Why not? What happens when you do?

Comment: after using child method one time,then its not showing child method again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the Xamarin client only allows a single call to `Child()` as all official SDKs allow you to chain those.

Luckily you can put the entire path in a single call, by separating the segments with `/`. So:

```
firebase.Child("Users/nhUHmmu8HJimlo").PutAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));
```